# Counting the Values of the field in AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a field called `travelinterest`and data extension name called `testforelavaran`. i dont know how many values in that field, suppose if that field contains four values, (col1,col2,col3,col4) and i want to count the values using rowcount, by using for loop and i will concatenate all the four values by using semicolon

I have tried:

```
%%[ 
var @travelinterest, @rows, @rowCount,@interestsTemp
set @rows = LookupRows("testforelavaran","travelinterest", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
for @i = 1 to @rowCount
set @interestsTemp = concat(
    iif(empty(@travelinterest[i]),'',concat(@travelinterest[i],';'))
]%%
```

but it is not working, please help me with AMPScript code,

My output will be - output value is `%%(travelinterest)%% (col1;col2;col3;col4)`

Comment: What error is it giving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference row-set elements like that in AMPScript.  You'll have to do something like this:

```
%%[ 

var @lookupValue, @travelinterest, @rows, @rowCount, @interestsTemp
set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("WHATEVERLOOKUPVALUEHERE")
set @rows = LookupRows("testforelavaran","WHATEVERLOOKUPCOLUMNHERE", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
set @interestsTemp = ""

if rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount
        set @row = row(@rows,1)
        set @travelinterest = field(@row,"travelinterest")
        output(concat("<br>@i: ", @i, ", @travelInterest: ", @travelInterest))
        set @interestsTemp = concat(@interestsTemp,";",@travelinterest)
    next @i

endif
]%%
%%=v(@interestsTemp)=%%
```